# Space appears above form (in Chrome only)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a form, which has a legend and a set of fields.  I'm using Bootstrap 2.x to style it.  For some reason, space appears above the form, but in Chrome only (it renders fine in IE10 and Firefox).  I've pared it back to just the basics to demonstrate the issue I'm having:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Legend</legend>

        <div class="control-group">
            <!-- This div results in the space appearing above the form -->
            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

If I remove the class="control-group" from the div wrapping the input field, the space magically disappears, despite seemingly having nothing to do with this issue.  I've checked all the margins and padding of everything in Chrome, and there's nothing, so I don't know where this spacing is coming from.  I need to use this class on these field divs, as I'm implementing a horizontal form.  I'm pulling my hair out trying to work out how to fix this issue - any ideas?  Here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/christhecoder/kDrVH/3/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kDrVH/10/

```
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css");

legend+.control-group{
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

you get 20 margin from this: `legend+.control-group`

Comment: OK, wow, that was quick.  I can't even mark it as answered, as they're making me wait 5 minutes!  Thanks for that - been scratching my head for an hour on this! How do you identify this? The Chrome debugging tools aren't showing me any margin at all, in neither metrics or computed style, making it incredibly hard to track it down.

Comment: Well I did inspect your form on jsFiddle with chrome, apparently you missed it. Rest for a bit :)

Comment: OK, I see it now.  Was very confused as the margin-top is appearing against the control-group div, and not the legend (as I would have expected).  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This is because bootstrap CSS rules for `<legend>` has `margin-bottom:20px`

Just add a CSS rule:

```
legend {

margin-bottom: 0px;

}
```

Also you can add this only to your legend label:

```
<legend style="margin-bottom: 0px;">

// Whatever you want

</legend>
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kDrVH/11/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but a touch later than the first correct answer, but an upvote for your effort.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Please bear on mind that applying @Panagiotis George Raditsas solution will works only when you have a legend + div class = control group.  If you use only legend you'll have the same problem :)

Comment: Thanks :). For my particular scenario, that's not an issue, but you're probably right - having a css rule targeting the legend only is generally a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
legend+.control-group {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Use this.
It will preserve your current layout and remove space above the form.

```
legend+.control-group {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this is the offending css rule as also identified by the other two answerers, but I disagree with modifying the bootstrap CSS as you're suggesting as I think it's better to override the existing rules with my own, making it possible to upgrade to new versions of bootstrap as they come available.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize it is bootstrap css I was modifying.